# which is better to use request.getParameter() or @RequestParm?

Tags: java, spring

Which way is considered as better Software Engineering practice in spring:

1) using the spring annotation @RequestParam

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSomeThing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public boolean doSomeThing(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
    boolean success = false;
    // do the logic
    return success;
}
```

2) using the request method getParameter

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSomeThing2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public boolean doSomeThing2(HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean success = false;
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    // do the logic
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Primarily opinion-based: the first one!

Comment: please post this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Same, I prefer the first, allow to skip some boilerplate code, make it more readable imo

Comment: @arthur as it stands, the question is off-topic on CR. It got cross-posted [by ayman and immediately got downvoted and closed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192131/which-is-better-to-use-request-getparameter-or-requestparm). Please don't redirect users to other StackExchange sites without checking their rules. For more information about CR, see [the guide for SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `@RequestParam` annotation because that way your code is **more readable** and **easier to unit-test**.

**Why more readable?**
Because it is clear that you depend on HTTP API only for that single parameter. `HttpServletRequest` is big object, you could do many things with it. An in this case you are using only very small subset of that functionality. Code is more readable when method signature is as specific as possible. Having parameter of type `HttpServletRequest` is less specific that parameter of type `String`.
It is in line with **Interface segregation principle** (client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.)

**Why easier to test?**
Using `@RequestParam`, you do not have to mock anything!
If you have `HttpServletRequest`  as parameter then for unit test you have to carefully mock that object -carefuly mocking every invocation of getParameter.

Comment: Another advantage is the automatic conversion: the RequestParam can be an int, or a LocalDate, or a Long, etc. And a proper error response will be sent back if the value is not convertible.

Comment: Does @RequestParam processing involves internal calling of request.getParameter() ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep i agree with the @RequestParam annotation i personally used in my
 spring-mvc application for CRUD operations and and many other operations like to display persisted table on the jsp page and all..